# Pass vars trough command line in mapping by Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm configuring a job to deploy my terraform infrastructure and I need to pass by command line a var include in a mapping. Like that:

**my.tfvars:**

```
nodegroups = {
    platform = [
         {
           "nodeversion" = "1.0" (Var to use)
           "backup" = false,
         }
    ]
}
```

Then I have to pass dynamically by command line this var to use in a jenkins job, something like that:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var={nodegroup.platform.nodeversion=1.0}
```

It's possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should be possible.

But it would look like this according to [Terraform's Variables On The Command Line documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line).

```sh
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var='nodegroups={"platform": [{"nodeversion": "1.0"}]}'
```

However, I would strongly encourage you to use a .tfvars file for complex input values. And in the case you have above, you're really only supplying one variable value. Is it really necessary to have an object inside of an array inside of an object?